# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json accessing json value

Tags: json, powershell, convertfrom-json

I have a json file that I'd like to convert to csv. However, the actual value is nested inside `reading` key that I need to access. It returns `System.Object[]` in which I know I have to access this, but I don't know how.

the following is the `result.json` file,

```
{"totalNumberOfReadings":1488,
    "readings":
        [
           {"meterNumber":"xxxxx","date":"2022-02-01 00:00","reading":0.0,"status":"AsRequested"},
           {"meterNumber":"xxxxx","date":"2022-01-31 23:30","reading":0.0,"status":"As Requested"},
           {"meterNumber":"xxxxx","date":"2022-01-31 23:00","reading":0.0,"status":"As Requested"},
           {"meterNumber":"xxxxx","date":"2022-01-31 23:00","reading":0.0,"status":"As Requested"},
        ]
}
```

My script is like this

```
C:\> (Get-Content -Raw result.json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

the output is this

```
"totalNumberOfReadings","readings"
"1488","System.Object[]"
```

This is just the summary/metadata. I want the actual content inside the key's value, how to access the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use member access:

```sh
(Get-Content -Raw result.json | ConvertFrom-Json).readings | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

...or only pipeline commands:

```sh
Get-Content -Raw result.json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object readings | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`ForEach-Object readings` is the [short form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-6-get-property-values) of `ForEach-Object -MemberName readings`.

Comment: thanks, the first one works just fine for me!